# Python 3.6 ~ AttributeError: module 'servicemanager' has no attribute 'Initialize' ~ When creating windows service exe

Tags: python, windows, service, python-3.6, servicemanager

When using any version of `servicemanager` with `Python 3.6.6` I get `AttributeError: module 'servicemanager' has no attribute 'Initialize'*`

Code Snippet:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(RelayService3)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(RelayService3)
```

This seems to be the standard main function of any `windows` service written in `python`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I think install servicemanager for error:

```
\Python38-32\Scripts\pip3 uninstall servicemanager
```

After it works.

Comment: It looks like pywin32 provides servicemanager, and installing the standalone library conflicts with that version.  Uninstalling servicemanager 2.0.10 worked for me.